# How to protect angularJS controller from minify

Tags: angularjs, controller, minify

So I know that I need to use `[]` to secure my code before minification. For example:

```
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'HOORAY!'; 
}]);
```

But how to do that when I am not using `app` as global variable, I've got

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('loginCtrl', Controller);

function Controller($scope, authService) {
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.login = function(login_field, password_field) {
        var loginData = {
            login: login_field,
            password: password_field
        };
        authService.login(loginData);
    };
}
})();
```

How to prevent it from problems during minification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same way:

```
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'authService', Controller]);
```

I strongly advise you to use ng-annotate, which allows using the simple syntax, and transforms it into minifiable code for you. That will make your code simpler, easier to read, and avoid a whole lot of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

When a controller or a service is a named function like in code above, it looks best when it's annotated with `$inject` (see [John Papa style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#manually-identify-dependencies)).

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('loginCtrl', Controller);

Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'authService'];
function Controller($scope, authService) {...}
```

Hoisting allows to place the annotation right above injectable function.

Comment: This solution look even nicer than JB Nizet one, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. That's how it's usually done, anonymous functions are annotated with inline array (like is shown in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45721757/3731501), named functions are annotated with $inject. It's a matter of style if you choose one or another.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be the same way:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
.module('app')
.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', 'authService', function($scope, authService) {
    $scope.login = function(login_field, password_field) {
        var loginData = {
            login: login_field,
            password: password_field
        };
        authService.login(loginData);
    };
}]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you may try  [grunt-ngmin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) before the minification that will searches and replace the minification with minify-friendly code.  Go to this link you will see example https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin#example